# Axios - How Can I Encode the Injected Value In My Get() Request?

Tags: vue.js, axios

I've got an axios call in my Vue app that's failing:

```js
axios.get(`parts/${item.number}`)
   .then(response => { /* do things */ });
```

...because sometimes the `item.number` contains a `/` …not good to have extras of those in a URL.  What's the recommended way to HTML encode that `item.number`?

Comment: The recommended way is to use `encodeURIComponent`, as the name suggests. This depends on how url is processed on the backend.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use **encodeURIComponent** to encode such parts of URL:

Example

```
// in browser console
encodeURIComponent('aaa/ddd')
"aaa%2Fddd"
```